# How to fetch actual image from the database

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having a hard time fetching the image from the database. I can only fetch the id of the image but the actual image file cannot.
this my code in display.php where im trying to fetch the image.

```
$sql="Select * from tblcenter";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$number=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $img_id = $row['img_id']; 
    $name=$row['name'];
    $mobile=$row['mobile'];
    $email=$row['email'];
    $address=$row['address'];
    $table.='
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">'.$number.'</th>
      <td><img src = "data:uploads/;base64,'.base64_encode($row['img_id']).'"style="width: 100px; 
       height: 100px"></td>
      <td>'.$name.'</td>
      <td>'.$mobile.'</td>
      <td>'.$email.'</td>
      <td>'.$address.'</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="GetDetails('.$id.')">Update</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteUser('.$id.')">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>';
    $number++;
}
```

[this is the result of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVszE.png)

[this the database/table of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhtLt.png)

Comment: The database doesn't appear to contain the actual image. Just a filename.

Comment: Assuming you've uploaded the image somewhere, like /images/, then you'd need to change your img src to images/ remove the base64_encode and replace img_id with name.  If you haven't got the image in a folder on the server, then you don't actually have the image as Quentin has said, you just have the filename.

Comment: actually, we created a folder where every uploaded image will be stored there, and right now whenever we upload an image there is an image that has been stored there.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
$sql="Select t.*,i.img_name from tblcenter t JOIN images i ON t.img_id = i.id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$number=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id=$row['id'];
$img_name = $row['img_name']; 
$name=$row['name'];
$mobile=$row['mobile'];
$email=$row['email'];
$address=$row['address'];
$table.='
<tr>
  <td scope="row">'.$number.'</th>
  <td><img src = "/images/'. $row['img_name'] . '" style="width: 100px; 
   height: 100px"></td>
```

Comment: Hi @user2022998315  We already did your suggestion still image doesn't appear. there is error appearing in status tab at network panel saying 404. is there any way i can upload the screenschot of the result so you could understand me much better.

Comment: What's your image's URL? Give me an example.

Comment: Is this is what you are referring to?
http://localhost/images/IMG-622c51e2f266d8.22895479.jpg

Comment: Yes. Just change the URL to your actual image URL.

Comment: here 
IMG-622c51e2f266d8.22895479.jpg
what should I do next?

Comment: Check your source code. You use which folder to store your images?

Comment: In the uploads folder.

Comment: I finally gets your code sir thank you. i just the changed the /image/ into what folder folder im using to store my images then i remove the first backslash. here's the updated code <td><img src = "uploads/'. $row['img_name'] . '" style="width: 100px; . anyway thank you very much sir.